# Is "creaseless" a word?

Tags: word-usage

Google tells me that it's a word. However, it gets underlined in red in most word processors. If it's not a word, what's a better alternative?

Example sentence:

> I watched Nishimura stuff her creaseless books into her shoulder bag.

Comment: What do you mean to say by "creaseless"?  That these books are in pristine condition?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, without folds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a word. Just because it isn't in a dictionary doesn't stop it from being a word. In this case, it is formed from the well-known word "crease" and the productive suffix "-less". It does [appear in some dictionaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/creaseless).

However, it may not be the word that you want. The fact that it is being underlined suggests that it is not in common use in standard English, and this is indeed the case. The more common word that expresses meaning that you want is "[uncreased](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncreased)". The meaning is a little different: a "creaseless book" would be one which is resistant to creasing whereas an "uncreased" book is one which hasn't been creased. You can buy "creaseless" shirts that don't require ironing. Some spell checkers also underline "uncreased" as it is potential typo of "increased"

Comment: Just wanted to add: "creaseless" could mean the same thing as "uncreased": not all "-less" words refer to things that are resistant to being put into certain states. That's true for stuff like stainless steel, but something that is e.g. "motionless" is just not moving at the moment, not resistant to being moved. "Uncreased" is a better word for this meaning, but it's not possible to rule this out as a possible meaning of "creaseless".

Comment: It could, in context, mean the same thing as "uncreased", but that is not the main meaning. See the dictionay reference.